# Update table through row_number()

Tags: oracle

I've a table ANAGRAFICA in my db with 4 names: fabio, mrco, marco, mchele but mrco and mchele are incorrect (the column is NOME). I use this query to select a name through the row number:

```
SELECT NOME FROM 
   (SELECT NOME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (NULL)) R FROM ANAGRAFICA)
   WHERE R = 2;
```

and for example it gives me 'mrco'. Great,but how can i modify my query to update in order to correct that name on that particular row number?

Comment: Add a column to the table that is integer, then update it to have ROW_NUMBER() in it, then do an update based on that, otherwse your numbering won't be stable. Or forget rownumber and use ROWID

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output. Rows in a SQL table have no inherent row order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So say you; that's different in my database:

```
SQL> select nome,
  2         row_number() over (order by null) r
  3  from anagrafica;

NOME            R
------ ----------
mrco            1
fabio           2     --> 2 isn't "mrco" but "fabio"
marco           3 
mchele          4

SQL>
```

How come? Because `ORDER BY NULL` is as good as if there were no `ORDER BY` clause. In other words, those row numbers are useless; you could've used `ROWNUM` and get the same final result (useless).

How can you tell whether "fabio" is incorrect (or correct)? Or - OK, let it be "mrco" - what will you update its value to?

From my point of view, the only meaningful option is

```
SQL> update anagrafica set nome = 'marco' where nome = 'mrco';

1 row updated.
```

---

Anyway: if it were a problem that actually makes sense, `rowid` pseudocolumn might be useful. Here's how:

```
SQL> select nome,
  2         row_number() over (order by null) r,
  3         rowid
  4  from anagrafica;

NOME            R ROWID
------ ---------- ------------------
mrco            1 AAAF3xAAEAAAAuDAAA
fabio           2 AAAF3xAAEAAAAuDAAB
marco           3 AAAF3xAAEAAAAuDAAC
mchele          4 AAAF3xAAEAAAAuDAAD

SQL>
```

Use it in `update` as:

```
SQL> update anagrafica a set
  2    a.nome = 'little'
  3    where a.rowid = (select b.rwd
  4                     from (select row_number() over (order by null) r,
  5                                  rowid rwd
  6                           from anagrafica
  7                          ) b
  8                     where b.r = 2
  9                    );

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from anagrafica;

NOME
------
mrco
little
marco
mchele

SQL>
```

It updated row for which `row_number` analytic function returned value equal to `2`. Once again - as you put it, you can't really tell which row it is (and certainly can't update it to a "valid" value because you don't know what you're updating so you can't specify a new value).

Comment: "Use it in update as:...."   when i try this it udpate the row 4 in every case. why? it's incorrect?

Comment: Exactly - you can't know what will be updated because of ORDER BY NULL. It just takes some "random" row. What I tried to say & demonstrate is that such a principle is pretty much useless. You *can* write such a query (as I showed you), but its usage is doubtful.